# How can I get the native SOL balance of a wallet using web3.js?

Tags: web3.js

Given the address of a solana wallet, how can I get its SOL balance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import { Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';

const connection = new Connection("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com");
const walletKey = new PublicKey("D33XEQK2xnLBp6LSzpTR3PS1CL6nZyB5QEKpXQxbUVMx");
//The following returns the balance in LAMPORTS - https://docs.solana.com/terminology#lamport
const balance = await connection.getBalance(walletKey) 
//So we convert it to SOL
const solBalance = balance / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
```